# sweetalert2 multimple inputs y ajax

Tags: ajax, input, sweetalert2

necesito hacer una llamada a una api que procesa los datos.
tengo mi codigo de sweetalert2 donde funciona bien con un input pero al cambiar el codigo para que pueda ingresar mas de un input no se como acceder al valor ingresado.

```
function nombre(nombre, apellido) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Editar nombre',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Guardar',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            html: '<input id="nombre" class="swal2-input">' +
                '<input id="apellido" class="swal2-input">',
            preConfirm: (login) => {
                return fetch(
                        nombre = $("#nombre").val(),
                        apellido = $("#apellido").val()


                        `user/nombre/` + nombre
                    )
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw new Error(response.statusText)
                        }
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        Swal.showValidationMessage(
                            `Error: ${error}`
                        )
                    })
            },
            allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: `${result.value.message}`,
                    onClose: window.setTimeout(function() {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 1500)
                })
            }
        })
    };
```

mi pregunta es comoaccedo a esos datos que ingreso en el html?

Comment: ¿Que error te da el código?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta tomar los valores de tus input fuera del fetch. Además no es necesario que ingreses parámetros si los valores los tomaras de los input. Espero haberte ayudado! Saludos.

```js
function nombre() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Editar nombre',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Guardar',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            html: '<input id="nombre" class="swal2-input">' +
                '<input id="apellido" class="swal2-input">',
            preConfirm: (login) => {
                /* Aqui tomas los valores */
                var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
                var apellido = $("#apellido").val();
                
                return fetch(
                        /* Aqui colocas las variables a tu api */
                        apellido + `/user/nombre/` + nombre
                    )
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw new Error(response.statusText)
                        }
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        Swal.showValidationMessage(
                            `Error: ${error}`
                        )
                    })
            },
            allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: `${result.value.message}`,
                    onClose: window.setTimeout(function() {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 1500)
                })
            }
        })
    };
    
nombre();
```